# How to make an action for a map annotated button in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, annotations, mkmapview, segue

Im quite new to swift programming and i am wanting to make an app with a MKMapview that contains multiple annotations with buttons that segue to other UIViewControlers. Is it possible for me to create an action like you would normally do with a regular UIButton? If not, How can i segue to other UIViewControllers?

Comment: Can't you just add a target to the buttons that goes to a function? Or similarly connect the buttons to an IBAction? I haven't worked with MKMapview before, but I can't imagine it would be much different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an Custom Annotation View:

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    // add here a button
    var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton // button with info sign
    yourView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
}
```

And then check when the button is pressed:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView{
        print(view.annotation.title) // your annotation's title
        //Perform a segue here to navigate to another viewcontroller
        self.performSegueWithIdentifiert("yourSegue")
    }
}
```